# git: diff between two commits, only for the files listed in a third commit?

Tags: git, diff

I'm using git svn, and needed to merge an svn-backed project branch from trunk. Attempts to use native svn merge messed up, so trying to be careful I created two plain git branches, one from trunk, one from my project branch, and used git merge between these new branches.

I now want to examine the changes between the project and trunk branches, but only for the files added/removed/changed in the merge I created - there's been quite a lot of work on both branches, although little actual overlap.

I cooked the following up which works, but doesn't feel elegant:

```
$ git diff soa-2237-from soa-2237-to $( git show HEAD |
       grep -E '^[-+]{3}' |
       cut -c7- |
       sort -u)
```

Given that I've already done the hacky merge, is there a more elegant expression of this diff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, instead of using `git show HEAD | <hacky grep/cut/sort stuff>` to get your list of files, you could use `git diff --name-only HEAD~1`, which is a bit less ugly, and lists the file names that had changes in the between the current `HEAD` and it's first parent.

You also should probably separate file names from the rest of the command, like so:

```
git diff branch1 branch2 -- $( git diff --name-only HEAD~1 )
```

That'll help if you ever run into files that have names starting with `-`.

Note, you could also do this referencing a third branch that is not the one you're on:

```
git diff branch1 branch2 -- $( git diff --name-only branch3~1 branch3 )
```

In that case you have to name the two commits to compare to get your file list, since the default `HEAD` argument won't be applicable.

Comment: Thanks, that's much prettier. I must have read the diff man page in the past, but the grep/cut stuff flows naturally to my fingers.